# Verify pending forwarding address with confirmation code in Gmail API

Tags: python, api, gmail-api, google-developer-tools

I'm creating a forwarding address for my Gmail account with Gmail API. I know that if function

```
service.users().settings().forwardingAddresses().create(userId='me', body=address).execute()
```

returns a result with a `verificationStatus` of `pending`, the recipient has to verify the email with a link or a verification code.

I can enter the verification code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Bzd.png) in Gmail `Settings>Forwarding` , but is there a way where I can enter the verification code with the Gmail API?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/56048196/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Gmail API documentation, if Gmail requires verification for a forwarding address, [a verification message is sent to the target email address and returned status is 'pending'](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/forwarding_settings). The owner of the target email address must complete the verification process before it can be used.

Unfortunately, the Gmail API does not have a verify method for forwarding addresses. The list of methods and paramaters for the Users.settings.forwardingAddresses method can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses) where it details that on call of `forwardingAddresses.create(args)`:

"...if ownership verification is required, a message will be sent to the recipient and the resource's verification status will be set to `pending`; otherwise, the resource will be created with verification status set to `accepted`.